# Offline image upload for Meteor.js app

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, html5-appcache

There is a Meteor.js app, which is suppose to stay fully functional in offline mode. This app enables users to upload their images and use those images to create content within the app.

Question - how to approach image upload in the Meteor.js app, so that the app stays fully functional in offline mode?

My thoughts so far:

--There is Meteor Offline Data project, but it is still very much work in progress, and it only works for text content: https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data

--In offline, when adding the image in the app, I could detect offline mode and utilize HTML5 File API for using the image locally

--When online is detected, the image is uploaded to the server behind the scenes

--In online content with images is downloaded to the app and saved for offline usage using App Cache

There are still many things unclear, so any hints are appreciated at this point.

Comment: Meteor Appcache package gives the ability to cache js sources, Meteor Offline data is a project in progress and the author was supported by Meteor Core team. The problem with caching images: usually appcache is limited to 5mb which is hardly enough for storing javascript, if you want a stand-alone app, have a look at https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit which will allow you to serve assets from localhost.

Comment: Thanks, this 5mb limitation is good to know. The app is suppose to handle both offline and online modes, so it is not really standalone.

Comment: I always thought images should be cached by browser in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try collectionFS, https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/collectionFS, as it make a client side collection that the file is added to. The clientside collection should sink when the internet reconnects.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, looks interesting, have to try!